# Print seperate csvs by month in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi i have a dataframe where it looks like this:

```
date              title
1939-01-01        one
1939-01-01        two
1939-01-02        three
1939-01-02        four
1940-11-22        five
1940-11-23        six
```

The desired output is to print a csv file for every month like
**1939-01.csv** that contains all the values that are at the month of 1939-01:

```
date              title
1939-01-01        one
1939-01-01        two
```

Hope that's helpful and understandable, please leave a comment if there are any questions where i can help with.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this if date is a string:

```
for n, g in df.groupby(df['date'].str[:7]):
    g.to_csv(f'{n}.csv')
```

or this if date is datetime:

```
for n, g in df.groupby(df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')):
    g.to_csv(f'{n}.csv')
```